# Are Muslims encouraged to research other faiths?

Tags: halal-haram, other-religions

I'm a born Muslim. There is so many things in Islam that neither me nor many ordinary born Muslims understand (maybe they just take Islam for granted and don't feel a need to research, as opposed to those who researched religions and finally embraced Islam by will).

Is this encouraged by Islam?

I'm reading about many stuffs like **reincarnation**, **spiritual growth**, **archangels** and **helper guides**, **alchemy**,  **near death experiences**, "**meditation**" along with many related topics, while suspending any Islamic duties until I make up my mind and find out more.  I'm not saying Islam is false (or true yet); I'm very attached to Islam indeed. I want to know exactly what I'm believing in!

By other faiths, I do not mean Judaism or Christianity. Instead, other viewpoints about divinity, our souls, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Imam [Ibn BaZ](https://www.google.nl/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCEQFjAAahUKEwjN3ZPgrd7IAhVqlHIKHUJnDls&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FAbd_al-Aziz_ibn_Baz&usg=AFQjCNGqbyjp77p_rovBbBCXCFdfm0-mpw&sig2=4HYUDGzQq-F07BQu9-s6-Q) said:

> No, you should not ... Because it may cause you to be in doubt, and it 
>   contains 'Shubhat' (critics against Islam). The prophet PBUH when he
>   saw Omar reading the Taurah (Old testament in Christian's Bible) he
>   said: '**O Ibn Alkhatab (Omar), Are you in doubt ? I brought to you (the
>   religion) white and pure, and if Moses is still alive, he has nothing
>   to do but to follow me**'. Which means Muslim should not read other
>   books like Bible, Taurah or other. Unless you as, Alem Deen (Scientist/Scholar in
>   religion), needs to reply to Christians and Jews ...

Resource: http://www.binbaz.org.sa/node/10748 [In Arabic]

Also Imam [Mukbel Ben Hadi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muqbil_bin_Hadi_al-Wadi%27i) said:

> We don't advise this, the prophet PBUH said in Sahih Bukhari by Abu
>   Hurrayra: "**Don't believe Ahl Ketab (Christians and Jews) and don't
>   assume they are liers, but say: we do believe in Allah and what He
>   sent to us**", In Musnad Imam Ahmed Hadith by Jaber: "**You either believe
>   falsely or deny truthly**" ... That's why I don't advise this. But for
>   Alem (Deen) who has a deep knowledge and who wants to reuse it to reply to
>   it, it is possible, in order to clarify the errors and contradictions
>   in these books ... even when while he does so, he (the Alem) is
>   against Islamic Dogma (in his action)

Resource: [Tuhfat-AlMujeeb, by Imam Mukbel Ben Hadi](http://majles.alukah.net/t50989/) [In Arabic]

Comment: I like your answer but what would be the difference between muslims and non muslims who are told not to question how is Nabii Issa the son of Allah (sw) ?

Comment: This answer fails to see that during the time of the Holy Prophet, people could directly ask him about any of their questions and doubts (since Prophet claimed to have access to Allah and hence knowledge of everything). This is incomparable to our time when we don't find answer to many of our questions and doubts, including about Islam itself, directly and clearly answered and articulated by the Quran or Hadiths. Hence the need to exercise our own reasoning and research.

Comment: This may also answer the question why some of the bright thinkers in the history of Islamic world turned to philosophy and science for independent study of truth.